# Iteration through OCaml lists with conditional statements

Tags: list, dictionary, iteration, ocaml

New to OCaml, so all I can come here with is some pseudo.

I'd like to write a function which takes in a list, then returns a new list with only odd integers.

So, simply iterate through the list, possibly use `%2` to find the odd integers, and append those into the new list.

Being new to OCaml, I've looked through what could be useful, such as `map`, `rev_map`, or `iter`, or possibly even `filter`?.

What would be the best to use, and how would you set it up?

Answer (score 5):

The most suitable function is `filter` in [List module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html). Look at its signature and description:

```
val filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

> filter p l returns all the elements of the list l that satisfy the
>   predicate p. The order of the elements in the input list is preserved.

you should know how to supply the predicate for checking odd integers as clearly described in your question.

Another less elegant solution is:

- Simply iterate through the list, and use an accumulator list to gather results.
- If an element is an odd integer, prepend it to the accumulator.
- Reverse the accumulator to get the correct order.

This solution involves in `List.fold_left` for accumulating results and `List.rev` for reversing a list.

Since you only ask which functions are appropriate, hopefully you're able to use them by yourself.

**EDIT:**

Because you shared your attempt on `List.filter`, here is one way to use it:

```
let odds xs = List.filter (fun x -> x mod 2 <> 0) xs
```

To be able to get further with OCaml, please take some time to read an OCaml tutorial. [OCaml tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ocaml/info) has quite a number of good resources for getting started.

Comment: Thanks. Of course I'm able to browse around and probably take a good guess at what functions will work best, but I'm just having trouble understanding the syntax.

If I were to use filter, what I'm thinking would look something like:
let oddfunc mylist = 
List.filter (mylist x -> [if{x%2!=0} then, append to list

As you can see, I have a very poor understanding of the ocaml syntax, and am mostly just jotting down my pseudo ideas..

Comment: The type that pad quoted tells you what you need to know.  `List.filter` takes a function and a list and returns another list.  The function tells whether you want the element to appear in the result or not.  So the next thing you need is a function that returns `true` if a number is odd.  It should work for any `int`, it doesn't have to (and shouldn't) know anything about `mylist`.

Comment: of course, instead of `List.fold_left` and reversing you could also use `List.fold_right`, but it's not tail recursive